# Rename ESP-IDF project folder on VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, esp32

After renaming project folder ESP-IDF build will return error:

> Build directory 'd:\githubs\fmc-320\firmware\vscode\test\01-log\build'
> configured for project
> 'd:\workspace\fmc-320\firmware\vscode\test\01-log' not
> 'd:\githubs\fmc-320\firmware\vscode\test\01-log'. Run 'idf.py
> fullclean' to  start again.

I know I can start a fresh new project with old code, but there is a clever way to do this by patching the actual project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually just performing a fullclean and rebuilding is enough. Did you try?

Comment: yes, it worked, I just needed read the warring, my bad, thank you